# No resuelve dependencia en gradle (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, programación-móvil, build.gradle

Estoy intentando hace una aplicacion que lea codigos de barra y para ello utilizo la libreria ZXing, pero al sincronizar el proyecto me dice que no resolver la dependencia. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque pasa esto?

La libreria que me causa problemas es

**implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'**

Mi gradle es el siguiente:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codigodebarras"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego captura de los mensajes de error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba a cambiar, arriba `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
por esto: `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` y... al menos por orden, mueve `implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'` al final de donde están las otras `implementation`.

Comment: @Alberto zt cual es el mensaje completo que despliega en color rojo??? Da click en "Show details" y agrega esta información a tu pregunta.  Con apply plugin: 'com.android.application' debería funcionar sin problema

Comment: Edite la pregunta, agregue los mensajes de error que surgen.

Comment: A. Cedano, cambiar por 'com.android.library' no resuelve el problema